# Working with json: how can I display json array in php randomly

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, decode

I have this code json code

```
[{"title":"Title 1","option":"Option 1"},{"title":"title 2","option":"Option 2"}]
```

I display it with

```
foreach ($query->getResult() as $row) {
    foreach (json_decode($row->keywords) as $msg) {
        echo $msg->title . "<br/>" . $msg->option . "<hr/>";
      }
}
```

How can I display this randomly?

Comment: [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) should do what you want

Comment: how can I use it on this please?

Comment: I tried   `shuffle($query->getResult());` but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the keywords array and then shuffle it before display:

```
foreach ($query->getResult() as $row) {
    $keywords = json_decode($row->keywords);
    shuffle($keywords);
    foreach ($keywords as $msg) {
        echo $msg->title . "<br/>" . $msg->option . "<hr/>";
      }
}
```